# Using excel vba to change the value of a dropdown menu on a website

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping, drop-down-menu

I am writing an Excel macro to fill out a form on a website. I have written the code that populate the text boxes easily enough, and found code to chose radio boxes, but I am having problems with choosing info from dropdown menus.

> **Example 'Gender':**
>
> The combo box has three options:
>
> ```
> Select / Male / Female
> ```
>
> I've tried a few variations on this:
>
> ```
> doc.getElementsByName("xs_r_gender").Item(0).Value="Male"
> ```
>
> ...but with no luck.

This is the web source code:

```
<td> <select name="xs_r_gender" id="xs_r_gender">
<option value="" selected>Select</option>
<option value="male">Male</option>
<option value="female">Female</option> </select></td>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

`doc.getElementById("xs_r_gender").selectedindex=1`
seems to do the trick. (Where 1 represents male)

Though it means I will need to do alot of lookups to determine what the value is for the items in my dropdown. (Easy enough for Sex, where there are only two options, but I have some comboboxes with up to 50 options). If anyone knows of a faster solution, that'd be great. In the meantime, Ill start doing up some tables!!!

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code assuming doc = ie.document

```
doc.getElementById("xs_r_gender").value = "Male"
```

Comment: doc.getElementById("xs_r_gender").value = "male"   Try this

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your code to call the function below.

```
xOffset = SetSelect(IE.Document.all.Item("shipToStateValue"), "Texas")
doc.getElementById("shipToStateValue").selectedindex = xOffset
```

Then use this for your function

```
Function SetSelect(xComboName, xComboValue) As Integer
    'Finds an option in a combobox and selects it.

    Dim x As Integer

    For x = 0 To xComboName.options.Length - 1
        If xComboName.options(x).Text = xComboValue Then
            xComboName.selectedindex = x
            Exit For
        End If
    Next x

    SetSelect = x

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Stack, works for me! My solution to operate an IE HTML combobox drop down turned out to be two parts.

Part 1 was to click the pull down, here's code:

```
Dim eUOM1 As MSHTML.HTMLHtmlElement
Set eUOM1 = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("input")(27).NextSibling
eUOM1.Focus
eUOM1.Click
```

Part 2 was to choose and click the value, like this (*actual element name changed):

```
Dim eUOM2 As MSHTML.HTMLHtmlElement
Set eUOM2 = ie.document.getElementsByName("[*PutNameHere]")(0)
eUOM2.Value = "EA"
eUOM2.Click
```

Here are references:[refs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/feaXM.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) method of `document` to apply a CSS selector of `option` tag with attribute `value = 'male'`:

```
doc.querySelector("option[value='male']").Click
```

or

```
doc.querySelector("option[value='male']").Selected = True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Function SetSelect(s, val) As Boolean

'Selects an item (val) from a combobox (s)
'Usage:
'If Not SetSelect(IE.Document.all.Item("tspan"), "Custom") Then
'something went wrong
'Else
'continue...
'End If

Dim x As Integer
Dim r As Boolean
r = False
For x = 0 To s.Options.Length - 1
If s.Options(x).Text = val Then
s.selectedIndex = x
r = True
Exit For
End If
Next x

SetSelect = r
End Function
```

Comment: A little explanation helps too.

Comment: I'm sorry. BUt I thought the comments in the code explained itself... or not? =D

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
doc.getElementById("xs_r_gender").value = "Male"
doc.getElementById("xs_r_gender").FireEvent("onchange")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

`doc.getElementsByName("xs_r_gender").Item(1).Selected=True`

or

`doc.getElementById("xs_r_gender").selectedindex = 1`

Where 1 is the male option (in both cases).

If the dropbox needs to fire some event in order to aknowledge your choice, it is likely that it will be the "onchange" event. You can fire it like so:

`doc.getElementById("xs_r_gender").FireEvent("onchange")`

If you ever want to be able to select an option based on the option's text you can use the function given by Lansman ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26063225/961546)) .
Based on the same answer, if you want to call the option by it's value property (instead of the text, you can just change the line `If xComboName.Options(x).Text = xComboValue Then` to `If xComboName.Options(x).value = xComboValue Then`).

This should cover all bases.

Comment: It does seem like a viable option, although it does not work in my case as well. The values of value="xyz" do not have any numbers assigned to them.

Comment: They don't need to have a number explicitly attributed to them. The number you should use corresponds to the position of the option (first/second/third/...). Alternatively, you can iterate over all options and compare the `.value` with your text until you find the option you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Copy from Here till last line:

```
Sub Filldata()

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

IE_count = objShell.Windows.Count

For X = 0 To (IE_count - 1)

On Error Resume Next    ' sometimes more web pages are counted than are open

my_url = objShell.Windows(X).document.Location

my_title = objShell.Windows(X).document.Title

   If my_title Like "***Write your page name***" Then

    Set IE = objShell.Windows(X)

        Exit For

    Else

        End If

    Next

With IE.document.forms("***write your form name***")

' Assuming you r picking values from MS Excel Sheet1 cell A2

i=sheet1.range("A2").value 

.all("xs_r_gender").Item(i).Selected = True

End with

End sub
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?