# Scraping dropdown menu selection

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I have a code for an automation using VBA, What I've managed to reach so far is the code is opening the url, entering the credentials, accessing the search page, however in the search page, I cannot select any of the options in the dropdown menu.

below is the code from the website, and the VBA code

```
Sub Test()

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1", Sheets("sheet1").Cells.Range("A1").End(xlDown))
Dim ie As Object


    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.Navigate ("Home page")
    Do
        If ie.ReadyState = 4 Then

            Exit Do
        Else
            DoEvents
        End If
    Loop

    ie.Document.forms(0).all("txtUsername").Value = ""
    ie.Document.forms(0).all("txtPassword").Value = ""
    ie.Document.forms(0).submit
    ie.Visible = True

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))

For Each cell In rng

    ie.Navigate ("search URL")

    DoEvents

   Set myElementsCollection = ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("Global Service Reference")

    ie.Document.getElementById("txtFieldValue").Select

    SendKeys (cell.Value)

    DoEvents

    ie.Document.forms(0).getElementById("cmdFind").Click

Next cell

End Sub
```

and the code for the webpage as its an intranet URL

```
<form action="search.asp?Find=1" method="post" onsubmit="return validate(this);">
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" width="100%">
    <tbody><tr>
        <td valign="top">
            <br><table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" width="100%">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <td colspan="3"><b><font size="3" face="cambria" color="#e60000">Please enter your search criteria:</font></b></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="20%">
                        <select name="cboFieldName">
                            <option value="0"></option>
                            <option value="1">Customer Name</option>
                            <option value="2">Customer Reference</option>
                            <option value="3">Site Name</option>
                            <option value="4">Site City</option>
                            <option value="5">Site Country</option>
                            <option value="6">Global Service Reference</option>
                            <option value="7">Customer Service Reference</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td align="center" width="10%"><font size="2" face="Tahoma" color="#000000">contains</font></td>
                    <td width="50%">
                        <input type="text" name="txtFieldValue" value="">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody></table>
        </td>
        <td width="25%" valign="top">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <td width="2" bgcolor="#003399">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td width="10">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>
                        <font size="2" face="Tahoma">
                        <input type="submit" style="background-color:#a3418f" name="cmdFind" value="Find">
                        <p>
                        <a href="login/welcome.asp" style="color:#666666" img="" src="../icons/doclink1.gif" border="0" align="center" width="19" height="19">All Customers</a><br><br>
                        <a href="search.asp" style="color:#666666" img="" src="../icons/doclink1.gif" border="0" align="center" width="19" height="19">New Search</a><br><br>
                        <a href="javascript:ShowHelp()" target="_self" style="color:#666666" img="" src="../icons/doclink1.gif" border="0" align="center" width="19" height="19">Help...</a>
                    </p></font></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody></table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
</form>
```

Comment: Set myElementsCollection =  ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("option") but I don't know how to advise any further on actual sending that value.

Comment: Thank you Qharr , I've updated the code above with what you mentioned and its still saying "Object Required" :(

Comment: Really sorry I can't help further with internal URLs :-(

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15003015/using-excel-vba-to-change-the-value-of-a-dropdown-menu-on-a-website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It should work:

```
Sub Select_dropdown_item()
    With CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "you_link"
        While .Busy = True Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        ''if the script fails, activate the delay
'        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")

'        Set post = .document.getElementsByName("cboFieldName")(0)''activate this line if you want to select using index
'        post.selectedIndex = 2

        ''the below portion will select the item using it's name
        For Each post In .document.getElementsByName("cboFieldName")(0).getElementsByTagName("option")
            If InStr(post.innerText, "Customer Name") > 0 Then post.Selected = True: Exit For
        Next post
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks SIM, can  you tell me where I should put in the above code :(

Comment: Kick out your existing code and paste it there. Only thing you need to do is put the url you wanna play with.

Comment: The code is above there, when I added the code to replace where I need to select the dropdown menu, I got "Automation Error"

Comment: This was the most explicit demo I could think of. I tested it locally using the html elements you pasted above and found the success. The rest you have to manage yourself. It's a very basic thing.

Comment: Thank you so much SIM .. it worked now, but its opening a new window, any idea how can I avoid this

Comment: I could give you all type of assistance If i could produce such difficulty you are facing right now. It's really hard to provide any hypothetical solution without facing the real web. Good luck.